# undefined local variable or method `application_controller' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, memcached, passenger

I have a problem with setting up rails application. We use rails 3 (we also use memcached), and have I installed everthing (DB, ruby, rubygems, rails, ...) and configure the DB. So if I run **rails server** the apllication starts ok.

For production we will use **Apache and Phusion Passenger**, both have been installed sucessfuly. When I restart apache I get this error:

*

```
[ pid=1557 thr=-608134948 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-08-13 12:51:05.974 ]: *** Exception NameError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (undefined local variable or method `application_controller' for main:Object) (process 1557, thread #<Thread:0xb78131b8>):
    from /media/Disc/ABC/CODE/TESTINGAPP/app/controllers/application.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /media/Disc/ABC/CODE/TESTINGAPP/config/environment.rb:5
    from config.ru:3:in `require'
    from config.ru:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1
```

*
First I thought that it might be sometnig with memcached, like some missing module for apache, but I read that there is no configuration needed for apache/passenger.

My question is, why application doesn't start? Have I forgot to install or configure someting? I really don't know what might be wronge since the application starts ok with *rails server*.

Tnx in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this file:

```
/media/Disc/ABC/CODE/TESTINGAPP/app/controllers/application.rb
```

Since Rails 2.3 this file should be called **application_controller.rb** and not **application.rb**. Rename the file and it should work:

```
/media/Disc/ABC/CODE/TESTINGAPP/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
```